# Understanding Haskell RankNTypes Error message

Tags: haskell, typechecking, rank-n-types

I'm trying to understand RankNTypes.

Why does the compiler complain in this case can `a` NOT be `[a]`?

```
> :{
> | tupleF2 :: (forall a . a -> b) -> (a1, a2) -> (b, b)
> | tupleF2 elemF2 (x, y) = (elemF2 x, elemF2 y)
> | :}

> :t tupleF2  tupleF2 :: (forall a. a -> b) -> (a1, a2) -> (b, b)

> :t tupleF2 length

<interactive>:1:9: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘[a0]’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        a type expected by the context:
          forall a. a -> Int
        at <interactive>:1:1-14
      Expected type: a -> Int
        Actual type: [a0] -> Int
    • In the first argument of ‘tupleF2’, namely ‘length’
      In the expression: tupleF2 length
```

While the following typechecks fine? and `t` is OK with `t a`.

```
> :t tupleF length
tupleF length :: Foldable t => (t a, t a) -> (Int, Int)
:t tupleF
tupleF :: (t -> b) -> (t, t) -> (b, b)
```

Is the above failure to compile only happens with enabling `RankNTypes`. Any pointers in understanding what is happening would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what `tupleF` is in your second example, but in the first one the reason for the error seems clear.  `tupleF2` expects an input of type `forall a . a -> b` - that is, a function which can take *any* input and produce an output of fixed type `b`. I'm not sure if any such functions exist, except for `const x` where `x :: b` - but `length` clearly isn't one. For example you cannot apply `length` to an `Int`

Comment: And whatever `tupleF` is, there is no `forall` in its argument type, so it can accept literally any function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`forall a . a -> b` is the type of a function `f` that can convert a value of any type `a` to some value of type `b`. Note that `f` must be ready to accept absolutely anything as input, i.e. all of these must type check

```
f ()
f 32
f True
f 'a'
f "hello"
f (True, [2], False)
```

`length` does not satisfy the requirement since e.g. `length ()` is ill typed -- `length` wants a foldable (like a list) as input, and `()` is not OK.

Hence, `tupleF2 length` is ill typed.

Pragmatically, note that `f` can only be a constant function, like

```
f x = True  -- assuming b = Bool
```

Indeed, *parametricity* guarantees that only a constant function can have type `forall a . a -> b`. You can try `tupleF2 (const True) ((),"hello")` and obtain `(True, True)`.

Comment: Thanks, this appeared while I was typing a comment saying effectively the same. I'm not confident enough with higher rank types to have made it an answer, but I'm glad I was essentially correct.